# Not able to download Zip file from gmail which contains executable Jar in it

Tags: download, gmail, zip, executable-jar

I have an email almost 4 years ago, which has Zip file in attachments containing executable jar file. I want to download that file. But, nowadays gmail doesn't allow to send or receive any executable file. Can anybody help me how can I download that zip from from my email?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The easiest solution would be this one, it takes 30 seconds to do. Simply open your web inspector and delete the display:none property for the google drive button. The button will then appears and you will be able to download your file in your Google Drive. From your Google Drive, you will be able to download your file on your computer.

Cheers

Comment: In Gmail you can click Show Original and then Download Original. Once downloaded, rename the .txt file to .eml and open with a local mail client. From there, you can drag the attachment out of the email.

Comment: I found a very well explained and 100% working solution for this problem in one of the website:
https://www.solutionspirit.com/download-gmail-blocked-attachments

Answer (score 138):

> **Proceed at your own risk !!!!**

1. Open the email in your browser
2. Go to the arrow next to the reply button, and press `show original`
3. When the new TAB is opened simply click on "Download original" and rename the file to `email.eml`!
4. Now you can open that `eml` file with almost any email client (Outlook, thunderbird .... )

Comment: While blocked files are usually safe, consider uploading any dubious file to virustotal or some other service.

Comment: agreed! can I update the response to include that note ?

Comment: Step 3 won't work, but you can simply click on `Download Original` and change the extension to .eml

Comment: this works. 

seems like it should be easier; my 10-year old email accounts have various zip files that are needed randomly. I appreciate getting a warning, but I don't appreciate being prevented from downloading it.

Comment: @YounesRegaieg hahah i'll send an email to help@google.com and get it fixed asap! :) thanks again for the workaround!

Comment: Alternative to step 4: Remove the text around the base64 data in the eml file, save to `file.b64`, then `base64 --decode -i file.b64 -o file`

Answer (score 27):

[image]

Step 1. Click on **Show original** option as shown in the image. Clicking this option opens a new tab with the original, MIME encoded message.

Step 2. Wait for the complete page to load. This might take a long time depending on the size of the attachment and your internet speed. Once the page has loaded completely, copy the content and paste to notepad. Save as 0.txt(any name you can choose).

Step 3. Now rename file 0.txt to 0.eml

Step 4. open the file in Outlook or any email client. you will see the email with attachment.

This way worked for me.

Comment: Isn't that a replication of my answer ?

Comment: Is your answer has more detailed steps with screenshot?

Answer (score 15):

You can download it from the Android Gmail or Inbox app. Then you can put it in drive if you like to access it anywhere.

Comment: Works in Inbox for Android as well. Great!

Comment: I tried Gmail on Android again an is working fine. What's the error or problem?

Answer (score 11):

**1.** Download and install python 3.4 (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/)

**2.** Open up the mail that has the blocked attachment. Click on the `arrow` button next to `reply` and select `show original`

**3.** Wait for the complete page to load. This might take a long time depending on the size of the attachment and your internet speed. Once the page has loaded completely, save it. The filename will be `0.txt`. Save it in a directory which does not have any other text file.

**4.** Open python and copy the following code. Save it to the same directory as `0.txt`. Run the program by double-clicking on the saved `.py` file.

```
# Get your files that Gmail block. Warning message:
# "Anti-virus warning - 1 attachment contains a virus or blocked file. Downloading this attachment is disabled."
# Based on: http://spapas.github.io/2014/10/23/retrieve-gmail-blocked-attachments/
# Go to your emails, click the arrow button in the top right, "Show original", save to the same directory as this script.

import email
import sys
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
  if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Press enter to process all files with .txt extension.")
    input()
    files = [ f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.txt') ]
else:
  files = sys.argv[1:]

print("Files: %s" % ', '.join(files))
print()

for f in files:
  msg = email.message_from_file(open(f))
  print("Processing %s" % f)
  print("Subject: %s" % msg['Subject'])
  for pl in msg.get_payload():
    fn = pl.get_filename()
    if fn:
      print("Found %s" % fn)
      if os.path.isfile(fn):
        print("The file %s already exists! Press enter to overwrite." % fn)
        input()
      open(fn, 'wb').write(pl.get_payload(decode=True))
  print()
```

You should see your attachment downloaded to the same directory after some time.

Source- https://gist.github.com/stefansundin/a99bbfb6cda873d14fd2

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I got my files.

Comment: Should run: `python <code_file>.py <attach_file>.eml`
Wow, the only solution work for me.

Answer (score 10):

1. Open the gmail email in your browser
2. Go to the arrow next to the reply button, and press show original
3. download original and save it with extension .eml
4. open it in oulook

Answer (score 7):

Or if you are PHP programmer get mail source via mail menu option "Show original" copy file attachment base64 string save to file for example test.b64 and:

```
file_put_contents ('test.rar',base64_decode(file_get_contents('test.b64')));
```

Saves regular attachment file in test.rar

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a smart phone, simply open the email, save the attachment, connect your smartphone to your computer, open the Download folder in your smartphone by using windows explorer and copy the file to your desktop.

Or, you could also forward this email from your smartphone to another email address and download it from there.

Answer (score 4):

No need to struggle a lot. I struggled a lot in my browser, YouTube tutorials and some articles but finally my own idea worked.

I was trying to download sriyog_com.rar file which was blocked by gmail.

[file blocked by gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou7Bk.png)

THE BEST WAY :

Open the email which contains that blocked file in Mobile Application.
The save to Google Drive icon will appear 
[Mobile Phone Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiNte.png)
Save the file in Google Drive
[File ready to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozKmJ.png)
Now the file is ready to download.

Note : Its time saving rather than eml files and other long scripting.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you have smartphone, the easiest way is to open the gmail in gmail app and save the file to google drive(in gmail app save to google drive is active). go back to computer and open google drive and download the desire file.

Answer (score 2):

Connect your gmail on one of the mail clients like Polymail, fetch your emails, download whatever you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Open mail from Android

```
--> Go to the specific mail
--> You will find a download option 
--> Download the ***.zip/***.rar file 
--> Upload it to the google drive 
--> Now download it or use USB cable to transfer data to your computer.
```

It's working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.barfuhok.com/how-to-download-a-file-with-anti-virus-warning-on-gmail/

It worked for me the method 1 "**Method 1: Save email and open it in Outlook**"

After downloaded the original message I changed the downloaded file to **.eml**

Eg: original_msg.eml

In order to open the message with other email clients file must be in ".eml" format.

Then I opened the file in thenderbird, which is a popular  free email client.

Now I can able to download files.

Thats it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Adiyya much obliged in 2020 using Thunderbird with Ubuntu 20.04 still fine way to retrieve a bunch of music codecs I stuck there in Feb 2010 and just needed to retrieve long after Gmail changed their rules whenever that was; that they do not allow to send it anymore fair dues but to download your own seems a little extreme ...   so thank you

Answer (score 1):

Five Steps to Solve Virus Blocked or Executable Files from Gmail.

1. Select Show Original
2. Download Original
3. Web Search eml reader online or you can visit
4. upload the downloaded eml file (from point 2).
5. you should be able to view and download the blocked attachments.

   [Online EML Reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xyl4.png)
   [Show Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhu7v.png)
   [Download Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoKgF.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found out was to download the attachment or add it to your drive via Gmail app. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround : Simply access the same mail via gmail android app.. u can download it . no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the file via any email client that uses IMAP (maybe also POP) will allow downloading of the file.

Answer (score -2):

> Just click forward the email and then click on the composed email
>   **attachment**

your file will get downloaded